# Using if else statements on lambda expressions on a pandas data frame based on column names

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, if-statement, lambda

I have a data frame `df` that looks like the following:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[78.78, 77.26], 'b':[94.47,94.06], 'c':[0.72, 0.71], 'd':[0.19, 0.29]})
```

For the columns `a`, `b` and `c` I want to extract (into a list) the min values, while for column `d` I want to get the max value i.e. :

```
[77.26, 94.06, 0.71, 0.29]
```

I am mainly trying to get this done with lambda expressions

to get all the min values, for instance, I could:

```
df.apply(lambda x:x.min(), axis = 0)
```

I thought about something like (of course it is not working):

```
df_final.apply(lambda x:x.max() if x =='d' else x.min(), axis = 0)
```

I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37443082/using-lambda-if-condition-on-different-columns-in-pandas-dataframe?rq=1) which is doing something similar, though the conditional statement is based on the **values** of each columns, while I want my if else statement based on the column names.The thing is that `x` i.e. the iterable object is not the column names. How can I then apply if else conditions with lambda functions based on column names?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apply function to each cell in DataFrame that depends on the column name in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44938029/apply-function-to-each-cell-in-dataframe-that-depends-on-the-column-name-in-pand)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `name` attribute on the Series:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.max() if x.name == 'd' else x.min())
#a    77.26
#b    94.06
#c     0.71
#d     0.29
#dtype: float64
```

Naive *Timings* for your reference assuming you don't have a lot of columns:

*Small data frame:*

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[78.78, 77.26], 'b':[94.47,94.06], 'c':[0.72, 0.71], 'd':[0.19, 0.29]})
​    
%timeit df.apply(lambda x: x.max() if x.name == 'd' else x.min()).tolist()
# 770 µs ± 9.88 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit pd.np.where(df.columns == 'd', df.max(), df.min()).tolist()
# 268 µs ± 7.93 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit df.agg({'a':'min','b':'min','c':'min','d':'max'}).tolist()
# 814 µs ± 22.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit df[min_cols].min().tolist() + df[max_cols].max().tolist()
# 1.02 ms ± 11.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit df.describe().loc['min','a':'c'].tolist()+df.describe().loc['max',['d']].tolist()
# 18.7 ms ± 317 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

*Large data frame:*

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[78.78, 77.26], 'b':[94.47,94.06], 'c':[0.72, 0.71], 'd':[0.19, 0.29]})
​
df = pd.concat([df] * 10000)

%timeit df.apply(lambda x: x.max() if x.name == 'd' else x.min()).tolist()
# 1.03 ms ± 16.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit pd.np.where(df.columns == 'd', df.max(), df.min()).tolist()
#1.81 ms ± 27.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit df.agg({'a':'min','b':'min','c':'min','d':'max'}).tolist()
# 1.07 ms ± 13.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit df[min_cols].min().tolist() + df[max_cols].max().tolist()
# 1.9 ms ± 30.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit df.describe().loc['min','a':'c'].tolist()+df.describe().loc['max',['d']].tolist()
# 25.7 ms ± 752 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Just a caveat: the timings are misleading in that for both "large data frame" and "small data frame" there are only 4 columns. If you had, for example, the same code, but `df` was `df.T`, `apply` would perform incredibly worse while other solutions would keep similar time

Comment: @RafaelC Yes. This does assume there are not a lot of columns. Maybe it's better to say there are practical cases if not a lot, the `apply` method is perfect fine.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
a = np.where(df.columns == 'd', df.max(), df.min()).tolist()
print (a)
[77.26, 94.06, 0.71, 0.29]
```

Answer (score 3):

In general, try not to use `apply` because it does not perform vectorized operations (i.e. it is slow).

Here, you can just select the columns you want and sum the lists

```
min_cols = ['a', 'b', 'c']
max_cols = ['d']

>>> df[min_cols].min().tolist() + df[max_cols].max().tolist()
[77.26, 94.06, 0.71, 0.29]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `agg` with dictionary:

```
df.agg({'a':'min','b':'min','c':'min','d':'max'}).tolist()
```

Output:

```
[77.26, 94.06, 0.71, 0.29]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `describe`

```
df.describe().loc['min','a':'c'].tolist()+df.describe().loc['max',['d']].tolist()
Out[276]: [77.26, 94.06, 0.71, 0.29]
```